# Java Swing Timer with SQL

Tags: java, sql, timer

I'm trying to setup a thread that loops every 100ms with every iteration querying a table in a SQL database.  Here is what I have in my public static void main class.  How can I define the connection outside of the listener and only call the query in the loop?

```
    // Database credentials
    final String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.0/";
    final String db = "db";
    final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    final String table = "table";
    public final Connection conn = null;

    // Define listner
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //...Perform a task...

            System.out.println("Reading Info.");
            try {
                Class.forName(driver);
                try {
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db,"root","pass");
                    Statement st = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
                    String sql = "";
                    st.executeUpdate(sql);
                    conn.close();

                } catch (SQLException s) {
                    s.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: Please try again!");
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR:");  
            }
        }
        };
    Timer timer = new Timer( 100 , taskPerformer);
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.start();

    Thread.sleep(100);
```

}

Right now it's giving me the following error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The final local variable conn cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Comment: Other problems: 1) you shouldn't be calling `Thread.sleep(...)` on the Swing event thread. 2) you should be doing your database calls in a background thread relative to the Swing event thread. 3) None of the code above should be made in static-land, in the main method. 1+ to @MJB's answer by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to. Connections are not thread safe per JDBC specification. Hence there is no reason or justification for Connection variable not being local to the thread. Why isn't it?

Comment: I am concerned with the speed of connecting to the DB every iteration.

Comment: Then use a Connection Pool such as C3P0. Then this issue goes away.

Comment: Okay.  Is that difficult to implement?

Comment: Not at all. It's easy. See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0 for the gory details. Read the first section. Not too hard eh? And yes, the cpds IS thread safe, so you can store it somewhere and use it.

Comment: A better recommendation for a JDBC connection pool these days is boneCP.

Comment: Quite possibly Marko- haven't had the chance to try it. Certainly of the major CPs it seems the most dev active.

Comment: I have recently started using it and it immediately showed an advantage. C3P0 was swallowing db exceptions and just reporting "cannot acquire connection from the pool", while boneCP had a fail-fast behavior, telling me exactly where my problem was.

Comment: I'm developing on a mac and I need the platform to be cross-OS... does boneCP have a Mac OS X download

Comment: bonecp is pure java, so such matters shouldn't be a issue

Comment: How do I pass the connection to an action listener?

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have an answer to your non-proximate issues, let me complement that with your proximate issue. You have this: `public final Connection conn = null;` which makes no sense. You have assigned `null` to a `final` variable. You may have added `final` because the compiler complained you are using a non-final variable in an inner class. What you probably want to achieve is a lazily initialized singleton. Remove the `final` modifier and then write a separate synchronized function that retrieves the connection and initializes it as needed:

```
private Connection conn;
private synchronized Connection connection() {
  if (conn == null) conn = createConnection();
  return conn;
}
```

Of course, you'd better make sure that you never use the connection concurrenly, but your use case doesn't call for that. Another issue with this naive approach to connection pooling are connections left in an invalid state.

Comment: There are so many issues with doing Connections this way instead of with a connection pool I cannot recommmend this.

Comment: I don't recommend this, either, for production. There might be educational value to it, though. And while we're at it, manual **transaction** management like that is even less recommendable.